# What is the exact meaning of "bid him be of good heart"?

Tags: expressions, phrasal-verbs, idiom-meaning

“He is a prophet of this people,” Waraqa assured his cousin after
hearing her story. “Bid him be of good heart.”

What is the exact meaning of "bid him be of good heart" here? Pls help.

Comment: 'Speak to him encouragingly' - literally 'Tell him to be cheerful/optimistic'.

Comment: "He has a good heart" means "He is kind".

Comment: @WeatherVane ‘having a’ good heart different from ‘being of’ good heart.

Comment: @Spagirl that was because the subject is a prophet. I would more usually say "Be of good cheer" to mean "keep your pecker up".

Answer (score 1):

To bid someone something is to offer them your hopes of that thing.

To "be of good heart" is to be cheerful or to be brave.

She is being asked simply to wish him well.